# why does my a star algorithm not work in javascript?

Tags: javascript, graph, graphics, p5.js, a-star

```
function algorithm(){
if(startPoint === true && endPoint === true){
//add the heuristic distance to the start position from the final position
startPosition.h = distance([startPosition.x, startPosition.y]);

let openList = []

openList.push(startPosition)
let closedList = []
  while (openList.length > 0){
    //print(openList)
    lowPos = 0;
    for(let i = 0; i < openList.length; i++){
      if(openList[i].f < openList[lowPos].f){
        lowPos = i;
      }
    }
    let currentPosition = openList[lowPos];
    //currentPosition.check()
    //if the currentPosition is the endPosition, retrace steps and find the path, then return this path
    if(currentPosition === endPosition){
      let curr = currentPosition;
      let ret = [];
      while(curr.parent != null){
        curr.path()
        ret.push(curr);
        curr = curr.parent;
      }
      endPosition.end()
      return ret.reverse();
    }
    openList.splice(lowPos, 1);
    closedList.push(currentPosition);
    let neighbours = neighbors(currentPosition);
    for(let i = 0; i < neighbours.length; i++){
      let neighbour = neighbours[i];
      if(closedList.includes(neighbour) || neighbour.colour == "black"){
        continue;
      }
      neighbour.check()
      let gScore = currentPosition.g + 1;
      let gScoreBest = false;
      if(openList.includes(neighbour) == false){
        gScoreBest = true;
        neighbour.h = distance([neighbour.x, neighbour.y]);
        openList.push(neighbour);
      }
      else if(gScore < neighbour.g){
        gScoreBest = true;
      }
      if(gScoreBest == true){
        neighbour.parent = currentPosition;
        neighbour.g = gScore;
        neighbour.f = neighbour.g + neighbour.h;
      }
    }
  }
}
 //meaning that either the path is not possible or the final node/initial node 
 has not yet been placed.
 return [];
}
```

this is my a star algorithm in p5, i'm trying to make an a star visualisation project, but for some reason a lot more of blocks are highlighted than expected.
[[image: what my algorithm shows me]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ILlOr.png
In reality it is supposed to be something like this: [image: what it's supposed to be]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nsF5r.png

The second picture isn't mine, its from someone else's implementation: https://qiao.github.io/PathFinding.js/visual/ = link to the second picture

I think it's something to do with the order of the line: neighbour.check() which changes the colour of the block.

Here is a diagonal solution, as you can see for some reason there is purple in the top left, that is my issue. The top left should not be searched, but it is for some reason.
[image: diagonal case]

If you need more of my code, please let me know.

Comment: It's not clear what your goal is based on the 2 examples provided.  The diagonal connection between the two points in your current algorithm simply appears to be the taxicab path, whereas the example of what it's supposed to look like happens to be an example of result that of course results in a straight line.  Can you show an example of what the result should be for a diagonal case?

Comment: @Trentium I've added what's needed, and added in a diagonal feature as well, but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it to fix, surprisingly the thing that was wrong was my distance formulae, I called the wrong variable.
[image]

here's what it looks like now! :)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are not checking the diagonals.
It is not a mistake. You are doing great.

Comment: thanks for the compliment, but my issue is that for some reason the top left is getting checked when it shouldn't, there should be a straight path to it instead of checking the top left, if you can help it'll be much appreciated